# OpenAL - being within AL_REFERENCE_DISTANCE causes no 3D rendering?

Tags: android, c++, openal

It seems when I use OpenAL and am withing the `AL_REFERENCE_DISTANCE`, I get no 3D rendering of the sound. It is played at max gain, but no 3D effect. Why is this?

EDIT:

For example, setting `REFERENCE_DISTANCE` to `10.0f` for max gain within that area

Comment: Adding the code you use and describing what you've already tried will greatly improve feedback. :)

Comment: When a source always plays at max gain, i.e. has no attenuation at all, chances are that you've set a combination of parameters (most commonly `AL_REFERENCE_DISTANCE = AL_MAX_DISTANCE`) that does not allow for evaluation of distance or attenuation calculations (most commonly because of divide by zero). Another popular reason for "no 3D" (but not for "always max gain") is playing a stereo sound. Stereo sources are just that, stereo. They're never rendered in 3D. However, as Michael said... more info needed.

Comment: @Damon your comment-answer has helped me and I converted it to a wiki answer. So is more clear for others with the same problem with OpenAL.

Answer (score 1):

*As per Damons comment:*

When a source always plays at max gain, i.e. has no attenuation at all, chances are that:

- you've set a combination of parameters (most commonly `AL_REFERENCE_DISTANCE` = `AL_MAX_DISTANCE`) that does not allow for evaluation of distance or attenuation calculations (most commonly because of divide by zero).
- Another popular reason for "no 3D" (but not for "always max gain") is playing a stereo sound. Stereo sources are just that, stereo. They're never rendered in 3D.